# html signature viewport fixing

Tags: html, iphone, mobile

i'm programming a html signature with this code:

```
<table border="0" width="480" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr >
    <td valign="top" width="110" height="114" rowspan="2"><img src="http://www.derkunsthof.ch/00_signaturen/derkunsthof.png" width="90" height="114" alt="Der Kunsthof"></td>
    <td valign="top" style="font-family: 'Helvetica 37 Thin', 'HelveticaNeue Thin', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height:18px; color: #636363;"><div id="sig" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Thin', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height:18px; color: #636363;" >MARCUS G. LINDNER</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td valign="bottom" style="font-family: 'Helvetica 37 Thin', 'HelveticaNeue-Thin', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height:14px; color: #636363;"><div style="font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Thin', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height:14px; color: #636363; text-decoration:none;">Der Kunsthof &minus; Restaurant<br>Z&uuml;rcherstrasse 28, 8730 Uznach<br>Telefon +41 55 290 22 11, Mobile +41 79 772 42 02<br><a href="http://www.derkunsthof.ch" style="color: #636363; text-decoration: none;">www.derkunsthof.ch</a></div></td></tr>
```

Unfortunately on the iPhone if i move from portrait- to landscape-modus the font increase instead of staying same size. I'm using for test iPhone 4s with ios7

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: any live example ? its strange happened without media queries.

Comment: it is strange, it happens only on mail. if i look the signature code though safari everything is ok: http://www.derkunsthof.ch/00_signaturen/dk_sig_mgl.html